# How to skip n step in for...df.itertuples

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, windows

My df structure likes below:

| country | city | area | month | pass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | aa | aaa | 1 | nan |
| A | aa | aaa | 2 | nan |
| A | aa | aaa | 3 | nan |
| A | aa | aaa | …… | nan |
| A | aa | bbb | 1 | nan |
| A | aa | bbb | 2 | nan |
| A | aa | bbb | 3 | nan |
| A | aa | bbb | …… | nan |
| A | aa | ccc | 1 | nan |
| A | aa | ccc | 2 | nan |
| A | aa | ccc | 3 | nan |
| A | aa | ccc | …… | nan |

What I need is when country + city + area = 'Aaabbb' skip the loop

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    index = row[0]
    key_words = getattr(row,'country') + getattr(row,'city') + getattr(row,'area')
    if key_words == 'Aaabbb':
       # what I means is key_words == 'Aaabbb' do nothing and do next('Aaaccc') directly, index step + len(months)
```

until now I still check the condition line by line, waste time

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    key_words = getattr(row,'country') + getattr(row,'city') + getattr(row,'area')
    if key_words != 'Aaabbb':
       #do something
```

Comment: You can use `continue`, or pre-filter the DataFrame

Comment: If you don't want to waste time, you probably shouldn't loop. Please give more details on the ultimate goal.